# Win Form application sending text to external application window

Tags: .net, winforms

I am trying to automate some tasks and was wondering if a Windows Form C# .NET 4 app can target a textbox in an external application and paste text into it?

If not what would be a good solution if any?

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you will need to use the FindWindow* and SendMessage Windows API calls

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindow

I have used this for a project so that we could collect a serial number from a program and send them all back to our office rather than needing the user to copy/paste it.

after using the `FindWindow` to find the Field you are looking for, then you can use `SendMessage` with a messageType of `WM_GETTEXT` to Get the text and to Set the text `WM_SETTEXT`